# The Common Language Runtime (CLR) was loaded in an unsupported manner

Tags: sql, .net, stored-procedures, frameworks, clr

I am trying to create a a stored procedure in SSMS that makes use of CLR.
I don't think the script matters, because it works on other machines.
The error I'm receiving is:

> Msg 10335, Level 16, State 0, Procedure Usp_CreateGISEvent, Line  19
> [Batch Start Line 12]
> The Common Language Runtime (CLR) was loaded in an unsupported manner.
> This can occur if an extended stored procedure or OLE Automation
> object running in SQL Server calls into managed code before the CLR
> integration runtime host loads the CLR. You need to restart SQL Server
> to use CLR integration features.

I enabled CLR settings via

```
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
```

Then restarted the SQL server.

However, when I run `select * from sys.dm_clr_properties`
the state value is still "*CLR is not loaded by SQL Server's CLR hosting code*".

What should I look for?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Windows, SQL Server and .NET do you have, and the .NET version of the DLL? Exact build numbers please.

Comment: @Charlieface Windows 11 Pro, OS build : 22631.3155, SSMS v19.3,  .NET Framework 4.5.2, How to retrieve the .NET version of the DLL?

Comment: Version of SQL Server not the SSMS client app. `select @@version`. The .NET version of the DLL when it was compiled in Visual Studio (or load it up into a decompiler such as dnSpy or dotPeek)

Comment: @Charlieface If I got you right, the sql server version is:
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-GDR) (KB5032968) - 16.0.1110.1 (X64)
and the assembly target framework is v4.0

Comment: Is SQL Server installed on that machine or a different machine? Why is it on .NET 4.5 if you are on Windows 11, shouldn't it be .NET 4.8.1? Maybe update SQL Server to the latest CU https://www.sqlserverversions.com/2021/07/sql-server-2022-versions.html

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah, I've already updated the .NET framework to v4.8.1 but I see this issue on both sql server v2019 and 2022 on other machines. 
I it even refers to .NET frameworks? I mean, there is no any error log .

Comment: Maybe someone is injecting a .NET DLL somehow? Antivirus (or an actual virus)? Or maybe a Linked Server driver?